# Spring batch - Could not commit JDBC transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I am using spring cloud data flow 2.7.1 with mysql 5.7.24 which executes a task with job related. the architecture used is Externalizing Batch Process Execution - remote partitioning (manger,worker) each partition is read from rabbitmq and there are several consumers connected by each worker (at the moment we use 1 worker with 2 consumers), sometimes there are partitions that fail with deadlock

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JDBC transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: (conn=2542684) Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doCommit(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:334) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:744) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:712) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor407.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.commit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.StepExecutionRequestHandler.handle(StepExecutionRequestHandler.java:64) ~[spring-batch-integration-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor421.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper$HandlerMethod.invoke(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:1092) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:581) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:477) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:355) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:108) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:95) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:170) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:444) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:318) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:266) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:229) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:170) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:198) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$600(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:61) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createAndSend(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:266) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:232) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1579) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer$$Lambda$795/000000003D931C00.invokeListener(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1486) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1477) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1421) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:958) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:908) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:81) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1279) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1185) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: (conn=2542684) Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:244) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:171) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:248) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:338) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.execute(MariaDbStatement.java:389) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.commit(MariaDbConnection.java:755) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.commit(ProxyConnection.java:366) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.commit(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doCommit(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:331) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readErrorPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1594) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1453) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1415) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:228) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:332) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar!/:na]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
```

Here the manager that is executed as task from spring cloud dataflow

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ConsolidationBatchProperties.class)
public class ManagerConfiguration {

    private static final String GET_MAXIMO_ADDRESS_LOCATION;
    private static final String INSERT_ADDRESS_LOCATION;

    static {
        GET_MAXIMO_ADDRESS_LOCATION = ResourceReader.readAsString("classpath:sql/getMaximoAddressLocation.sql");
        INSERT_ADDRESS_LOCATION =  ResourceReader.readAsString("classpath:sql/insertAddressLocation.sql");
    }

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private final ConsolidationBatchProperties consolidationBatchProperties;
    private final RemotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory remotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory;


    @Autowired
    public ManagerConfiguration(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                                StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                                @Qualifier("appDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
                                ConsolidationBatchProperties consolidationBatchProperties,
                                RemotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory remotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory) {

        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;

        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.consolidationBatchProperties = consolidationBatchProperties;
        this.remotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory = remotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory;
    }

    /*
     * Configure outbound flow (requests going to workers)
     */

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel requests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(requests())
                .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate)
                        .routingKey(consolidationBatchProperties.getQueueName()))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExecutionDeltaDao jobExecutionDeltaDao(final @Qualifier("batchDataSource") DataSource batchDataSource){

        JobExecutionDeltaDao jobExecutionDao = new JobExecutionDeltaDao();
        jobExecutionDao.setJdbcTemplate(new JdbcTemplate(batchDataSource));

        return jobExecutionDao;
    }

    @Bean
    public StartDateConsolidation startDateConsolidation(){
        return new StartDateConsolidation(this.dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExecutionDeltaExplorer jobExecutionDeltaExplorer(JobExecutionDeltaDao jobExecutionDeltaDao,
                                                               StartDateConsolidation startDateConsolidation){

        return  new JobExecutionDeltaExplorer(jobExecutionDeltaDao, startDateConsolidation);
    }


    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ColumnRangePartitioner partitioner(final @Qualifier("batchDataSource") DataSource batchDataSource) {

        ColumnRangePartitioner columnRangePartitioner = new ColumnRangePartitioner();
        columnRangePartitioner.setColumn("id");
        columnRangePartitioner.setDataSource(batchDataSource);
        columnRangePartitioner.setTable("GEOSITES_ADDRLOC");

        return columnRangePartitioner;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<AddressLocation> addressLocationReader(@Value("${customers:}") String[] customers, @Value("${mode:ALL}") String mode, @Value("${locations:}") String[] locations, JobExecutionDeltaExplorer jobExecutionDeltaExplorer) {

        AddressLocationSqlTransformer sqlTransformer = new AddressLocationSqlTransformer();
        sqlTransformer.setSql(GET_MAXIMO_ADDRESS_LOCATION);
        sqlTransformer.setCustomers(customers);
        sqlTransformer.setMode(mode);
        sqlTransformer.setLocations(locations);
        sqlTransformer.setJobExecutionDeltaExplorer(jobExecutionDeltaExplorer);

        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<AddressLocation>()
                .name("addressLocationReader")
                .dataSource(this.dataSource)
                .fetchSize(1000)
                .sql(sqlTransformer.getTransformedSql())
                .rowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(AddressLocation.class))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<AddressLocation> addressLocationItemWriter(final @Qualifier("batchDataSource") DataSource batchDataSource) {

        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<AddressLocation>()
                .dataSource(batchDataSource)
                .sql(INSERT_ADDRESS_LOCATION)
                .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public Step createAliasAndIndexStep(CreateIndexAndAliasTasklet createIndexAndAliasTasklet){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("createAliasAndIndexStep")
                .tasklet(createIndexAndAliasTasklet).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step migrateAddressLocationStep(final JdbcCursorItemReader<AddressLocation> addressLocationReader,
                                           final JdbcBatchItemWriter<AddressLocation> addressLocationItemWriter) {

        return stepBuilderFactory.get(MIGRATE_ADDR_LOC_STEP_NAME)
                .<AddressLocation, AddressLocation>chunk(1000)
                .reader(addressLocationReader)
                .writer(addressLocationItemWriter)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step masterStep(ColumnRangePartitioner partitioner) {
          return remotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory.get(MASTER_STEP_NAME)
                .partitioner(WORKER_STEP_NAME, partitioner)
                .gridSize(consolidationBatchProperties.getGridSize())
                .outputChannel(requests())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job consolidateAddressFromMaximoJob(final Step createAliasAndIndexStep, final Step migrateAddressLocationStep, final Step masterStep) {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get(JOB_NAME)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(createAliasAndIndexStep)
                .next(migrateAddressLocationStep)
                .next(masterStep)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Here the worker that runs outside the context of data flow, it is always listening for messages in rabbitmq

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ConsolidationBatchProperties.class)
public class WorkerConfiguration {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WorkerConfiguration.class);

    private static final String GET_ADDRESS_LOCATION_WITHIN_RANGE;

    static {
        GET_ADDRESS_LOCATION_WITHIN_RANGE = ResourceReader.readAsString("classpath:sql/getAddressLocationWithinRange.sql");
    }

    private final RemotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory remotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory;
    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private final ConsolidationBatchProperties consolidationBatchProperties;

    @Autowired
    public WorkerConfiguration(
            RemotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory remotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory,
            @Qualifier("batchDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
            ConsolidationBatchProperties consolidationBatchProperties) {

        this.remotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory = remotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.consolidationBatchProperties = consolidationBatchProperties;
    }

    /*
     * Configure inbound flow (requests coming from the master)
     */
    @Bean
    public DirectChannel requests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow(SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(listenerContainer))
                .channel(requests())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container =
                new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(consolidationBatchProperties.getQueueName());
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(consolidationBatchProperties.getConsumers());

        return container;
    }

    /*
     * Configure outbound flow (replies going to the master)
     */
    @Bean
    public NullChannel replies() {
        return new NullChannel();
    }

    /*
     * Configure worker components
     */

    @Bean
    public GeographicSiteProcessor geographicSiteProcessor(GeographicSiteApiClient GeographicSiteApiClient, GeographicAddressApiClient geographicAddressApiClient){
        return new GeographicSiteProcessor(geographicAddressApiClient, GeographicSiteApiClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticObjectItemWriter elasticObjectItemWriter(RestHighLevelClient client, ObjectMapper objectMapper, ElasticIndexProperties elasticIndexProperties){

        ElasticObjectItemWriter elasticObjectItemWriter = new ElasticObjectItemWriter();
        elasticObjectItemWriter.setClient(client);
        elasticObjectItemWriter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        elasticObjectItemWriter.setIndexName(elasticIndexProperties.getWritingIndexName());
        elasticObjectItemWriter.setType(elasticIndexProperties.getType());

        return elasticObjectItemWriter;

    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<AddressLocation> itemReader(
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['minValue']}")Long minValue,
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['maxValue']}")Long maxValue) {

        log.info("reading " + minValue + " to " + maxValue);
        RangeSetter rangeSetter = new RangeSetter();
        rangeSetter.setStartValue(minValue);
        rangeSetter.setEndValue(maxValue);

        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<AddressLocation>()
                .name("itemReader")
                .dataSource(this.dataSource)
                .sql(GET_ADDRESS_LOCATION_WITHIN_RANGE)
                .preparedStatementSetter(rangeSetter)
                .rowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(AddressLocation.class))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step workerStep(JdbcCursorItemReader<AddressLocation> itemReader,
                           GeographicSiteProcessor geographicSiteProcessor,
                           ElasticObjectItemWriter elasticObjectItemWriter) {

        return remotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory.get("workerStep")
                .inputChannel(requests())
                .<AddressLocation, ElasticGeographicSite>chunk(consolidationBatchProperties.getChunkSize())
                .reader(itemReader)
                .processor(geographicSiteProcessor)
                .writer(elasticObjectItemWriter)
                .faultTolerant()
                .retryLimit(5)
                .retry(MicroserviceException.class)
                .retry(TransactionSystemException.class)
                .skip(NullPointerException.class)
                .skipLimit(10)
                .listener(new LoggingSkipListener<AddressLocation, ElasticObject>())
                .build();
    }

}
```

Do you have any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Your stacktrace is truncated. Please provide the full stacktrace to be able to see the root cause of the issue. Moreover, please share your code to understand your setup and be able to help you in an efficient way, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: I put the new  stacktrace , i forgot to tell you that i am using mariadb client

Comment: Thank you for the update. However, as said in my previous comment, please share a minimal example that reproduces the issue to be able to help you.

Comment: The deadlock error always happens on a single partition

Comment: What are the transaction attributes at the worker side? I'm suspecting the problem is coming from having more than one consumer per worker. Have you tried a single consumer per worker?

Comment: Yes, indeed at this moment we have 1 worker with several consumers to make it faster, we can try 1 single consumer but it would take longer for the job

Comment: Could you be more precise with this question "What are the transaction attributes at the worker side? " I would like to understand better

Comment: Your workers are configured to execute a chunk-oriented step, right? This step is transactional. So my question is: what are the transaction attributes (isolation level, propagation, etc) of that transaction. This is key because the dead-lock is happening at the worker side and we should know the transaction attributes at that level. I suspect the deadlock is happening because two consumers are competing on a resource. Did using one consumer per worker fix the issue?

Comment: Hi, Yes the worker it is, the isolation level and propagation is the default values for isolation level is ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE, I'm going to test with 1 single consumer and I'll give you news, The most curious thing is that before it worked very well with mariadb

Comment: Hello we have tested with 1 single consumer and we have not had deadlock problems, but my question is to scale so should we use several pod workers with 1 single consumer and this formula would avoid deadlock?

Answer (score 0):

The dead-lock is happening at the worker side and I suspect the this is happening because two (or more) message consumers are competing on a resource.

> Did using one consumer per worker fix the issue?

> we have tested with 1 single consumer and we have not had deadlock problems, but my question is to scale so should we use several pod workers with 1 single consumer and this formula would avoid deadlock?

I'm not sure workers are expected to have more than one consumer. The idea of remote partitioning is that each partition is handled by a worker. Now how this partition is handled at the worker side is up to you. If you want to add another level of scaling on the worker side, you can try a multi-threaded step or a locally partitioned step instead of using multiple consumers.